# How to stop a delay if attribute is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Testing this out and I'm trying to figure out how to stop a delay if i click another attribute. I'll post the site address to make this explanation a lot better, but basically when you press menu my nav appears with a delay, when I press Assignment 6 I want everything else to hide, which it does, but I see that because I have a delay when it hides and it's not done delaying it will continue to print out the rest of the elements even though they are supposed to be hidden. Also a disclaimer, I've gotten a lot of heat on this site before because I think people think I expect an answer. This is not the case, I love to learn and although the answer would be helpful and I would be able to de-engineer it and learn it, I would much rather have some guidance. So yeah, I'm not just looking for an answer if anyone thinks that's what I'm on here for (I come on here when I can't figure it out any other way).

[site](http://iam.colum.edu/students/jordan.max/algorerhythm/a6.html)

my jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //$('ul').hide();
    $('ul li').hide();
    $('nav>li').hide();

    $('nav>h1>').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('nav>ul li:hidden').each(function(i) {
            $('nav>li').show();
            $('nav>h1').hide();
            $(this).delay(i*600).fadeIn(200);
        });

        $('nav>ul li:visible').each(function(i) {
            $('nav>h1').hide();
            $(this).delay(i*600).fadeOut(200);
        });

        return false;

    }); //closes a.btnDown

     $('nav>li').click(function (event) {
        $('nav>h1').show();
        $('nav>li').hide();
        $('ul li').hide();

        return false;

        }); //closes a.btnDown
}); //closes .ready
```

Comment: if I was writing in C#, or any programming lanuage, this would be in a loop, and I haven't learned yet if jquery has loops. <-- something I troubleshooted. Or even bool values, which I don't think jQuery has either.

Comment: both javascript and jquery have loops. javascript has bool values. jQuery is built from javascript.

Comment: You can in javascript, you mean just a simple if statement right?

Comment: "*I've gotten a lot of heat on this site before because I think people think I expect an answer*" - to those people I could only say "what other purpose does a Question and Answer site serve, if not the provision of answers?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout is a useful mechanism to solve what you are after. It waits for (at least) the delay specified, and executes the callback function.

```
var elements = $('nav>ul li:hidden');

var timeoutId;
function doAnimation(index) {
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
        if (index < elements.length) {
            $(elements[index]).fadeIn(200);
            doAnimation(++index);
        }
    }, 600);
}
```

The clue is to declare the timeoutId outside a recursive function, and assign it within the function. By doing it in a recursive fashion, you don't start the next timeout before the current timeout is finished, and it can be aborted at any time.

```
window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

I've made a little fiddle that demonstrates the concept, but I haven't implemented a complete solution. Hope this helps you get further with your project.

http://jsfiddle.net/pyMpj/

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your delays with `setTimeout` and clear them with `clearTimeout`

```
$('nav>ul li:hidden').each(function(i) {
    $('nav>li').show();
    $('nav>h1').hide();
    var fadeTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
      $(this).fadeIn(200);
    }, i * 600);
});

$('nav>li').click(function (event) {
    $('nav>h1').show();
    $('nav>li').hide();
    $('ul li').hide();
    clearTimeout(fadeTimeout);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I was close then I tried to do a clearQueue(), I find when I do yours though it doesn't do the nav animation at all.